# Unrequired hidden input based one radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three radio buttons: infistall, delivery and estock.

Each of radio button will show/hide some inputs that are required to fill.

when one of these radio buttons is clicked, then those some input will be shown and must be filled.

My question is how to make the required input become not required anymore when they are hidden.

This is the script that will shiw/hide the inputs based on its radio button.

```
  <style type="text/css">.box{display: none;}</style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
             if($(this).attr("value")=="EStock"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".EStock").show();
             }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="InfiStall"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".InfiStall").show();
             }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="Delivery"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".Delivery").show();
             }
       });
     });    
  </script>
```

---

```
    echo '<div id="method-detail-information">';                          

    echo '<ul id="delivery-method" style="width:488px; margin:10px 0; padding-left:12px;"><b>Metode Pengambilan Barang : </b> 
            <li class="method-of-approval"><input type="radio" name="method[]" value="EStock" required>EStock</li>
            <li class="method-of-approval"><input type="radio" name="method[]" value="InfiStall">InfiStall</li>
            <li class="method-of-approval"><input type="radio" name="method[]" value="Delivery">Delivery</li>
          </ul>';


    echo'<div class="Delivery box" style"position:relative; display:block; float:left; background:red;">
         <ul id="delivery-method" style="width:488px; margin:10px 0; padding-left:12px;"><b>Pilih Layanan Antar : </b> 
            <li class="method-of-approval"><input type="radio" name="deliveryService[]" value="JNE" required>JNE</li>
            <li class="method-of-approval"><input type="radio" name="deliveryService[]" value="TIKI">TIKI</li></ul>

         <ul id="delivery-address-wrapper">
            <li><span class="delivery-address">City</span>
                <span><input class="delivery-address-input" type="text" placeholder="City" required /></span></li>
            <li><span class="delivery-address">Address</span>
                <span><textarea rows="5" class="delivery-address-input" placeholder="Address" required></textarea></span></li></ul>
         </div>';

    echo'<div class="InfiStall box" style"position:relative; display:block; float:left; background:yellow;">
         <ul style="padding:12px; width:480px; margin:10px 0;"><b>Pilih Lokasi Infi Stall :</b> <br>
             <li class="method-of-payment"><input type="radio" name="location[]" value="Kemayoran" required>Kemayoran<br></li>
             <li class="method-of-payment"><input type="radio" name="location[]" value="Sunter">Sunter<br></li>
         </ul>
         </div>';

    echo'<div class="EStock box" style"background:yellow;">We will keep your order until you decide to have it soon
         </div>';
```

Comment: I was going to answer you previous question but you deleted it when I am done with answer, now I am scared to write answer.

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven  haha..come on, do not be shy

Comment: @AhmetCanGuven oh, man I am so sory for that because I have to edit  the question with more detail information. Thank you very much for your effort to help me. I do really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `removeAttr()` in order to **remove required attribute from input type radio inside li's** as shown :-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
             if($(this).attr("value")=="EStock"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".box ul li input:radio").removeAttr('required');
                $(".EStock").show();
             }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="InfiStall"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".box ul li input:radio").removeAttr('required');
                $(".InfiStall").show();
             }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="Delivery"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".box ul li input:radio").removeAttr('required');
                $(".Delivery").show();
             }
       });
 });
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

---

As commented by questioner he wants to remove value as well then you can try emptying the value or use `.removeAttr()` as shown :

```
$(".box ul li input:radio").removeAttr('value');
```

OR

```
$(".box ul li input:radio").val('');
```

OR

As correctly commented by **leo** in comments section you can add a disabled attribute to the field and disabled field values can never be posted to the server.

Comment: That's great. Then what if I also remove the value as well because I don't want to send the value to the database if it is not selected.

Comment: @klaudia..well yes you can do that or you can set value as empty with jquery `.val('')`...if answer solved your problem then accept upvote the answer so that accepted answer helps visitors also..thanks...

Comment: @klaudia  add 'disabled' to your input field and it will be not send any empty value

Comment: Yes I am going to accept the answer but it ask me to wait for one minute, just be patient, man. You will get the reputation because you are great. But will you edit your answer for me to show how to remove the value.

Comment: @leo, did you mean that I have to add `disable` by javascript?

Comment: @klaudia yes! just like removeAttr, you also can addAttr by js/jquery